# Why are 0s being read by R as NA?

Tags: r, na

I am working on creating some association rules for my dataset CatalogSales.csv.

I have used the same code on another dataset with no issue, and the only thing that I can find that's different about this dataset is that R is recognizing the 0 values as being NA.  I can find a lot of tutorials of how to turn an NA value into a 0, but I'm at a loss as to why these 0s are being recognized as NA and what the best way to fix them is.

Here is the code in full.  Note that I drop the columns with NA in the section about creating a bar plot.

```
> cross.sell <- read.csv("CatalogCrossSell.csv")
> head(cross.sell)
  Customer.Number Clothing.Division Housewares.Division
1           11569                 0                   1
2           13714                 0                   1
3           46391                 0                   1
4           67264                 0                   0
5           67363                 0                   0
6           72553                 0                   1
  Health.Products.Division Automotive.Division Personal.Electronics.Division
1                        1                   1                             1
2                        1                   1                             1
3                        1                   1                             1
4                        1                   1                             1
5                        1                   0                             1
6                        1                   1                             1
  Computers.Division Garden.Division Novelty.Gift.Division Jewelry.Division  X
1                  0               0                     1                0 NA
2                  0               1                     1                1 NA
3                  0               1                     1                1 NA
4                  0               1                     1                0 NA
5                  0               1                     1                0 NA
6                  0               1                     1                1 NA
  X.1 X.2 X.3 X.4 X.5 X.6 X.7 X.8 X.9
1  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
5  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
6  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> dim(cross.sell)
[1] 60004    20
> nrow(cross.sell)
[1] 60004
> is.data.frame(cross.sell)
[1] TRUE
> table(is.na(cross.sell))

  FALSE    TRUE 
  49980 1150100
> 
> 
> #View individual item names
> t(t(names(cross.sell)))
      [,1]                           
 [1,] "Customer.Number"              
 [2,] "Clothing.Division"            
 [3,] "Housewares.Division"          
 [4,] "Health.Products.Division"     
 [5,] "Automotive.Division"          
 [6,] "Personal.Electronics.Division"
 [7,] "Computers.Division"           
 [8,] "Garden.Division"              
 [9,] "Novelty.Gift.Division"        
[10,] "Jewelry.Division"             
[11,] "X"                            
[12,] "X.1"                          
[13,] "X.2"                          
[14,] "X.3"                          
[15,] "X.4"                          
[16,] "X.5"                          
[17,] "X.6"                          
[18,] "X.7"                          
[19,] "X.8"                          
[20,] "X.9"                          
> 
> #Create bar plot to view distribution of sales and remove NA values
> cross.data <- as.matrix(subset(cross.sell[,-c(1, 11:20)]))
> barplot(cross.data, main = "Individual Item Sales")
> dim(cross.data)
[1] 60004     9
> 
> #Check for NA values and class
> table(is.na(cross.data))

 FALSE   TRUE 
 44982 495054 
> sapply(cross.data, class)
   [1] "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer"
   [8] "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer" "integer"
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 539036 entries ]
> 
> #Create transaction database
> cross.trans <- as(cross.data, "transactions")
Error in if (any(from != 0 & from != 1)) warning("matrix contains values other than 0 and 1! Setting all entries != 0 to 1.") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.  Since I have already omitted columns 11:20 I shouldn't have any NA values but I obviously do, and when I go super old school and add up the number of NA = False and NA = True values I get the same number of values as my database total, so I know it's because R is reading the 0s as NA, but I don't know *why*.

Here's the first few lines as requested:

```
> readLines("CatalogCrossSell.csv", n=4)
[1] "Customer Number,Clothing Division,Housewares Division,Health Products Division,Automotive Division,Personal Electronics Division,Computers Division,Garden Division,Novelty Gift Division,Jewelry Division,,,,,,,,,,"
[2] "000011569,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,,,,,,,,,,"                                                                                                                                                                               
[3] "000013714,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,,,,,,,,,,"                                                                                                                                                                               
[4] "000046391,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,,,,,,,,,,"
```

I already tried removing the other 10 columns as I was creating the cross.data subset (in the boxplot section), but I was still getting the error.  That part of the code is below for clarity:

```
> cross.data <- as.matrix(subset(cross.sell[,-c(1, 11:20)]))

> head(cross.data)
  Clothing.Division Housewares.Division Health.Products.Division
1                 0                   1                        1
2                 0                   1                        1
3                 0                   1                        1
4                 0                   0                        1
5                 0                   0                        1
6                 0                   1                        1
  Automotive.Division Personal.Electronics.Division Computers.Division
1                   1                             1                  0
2                   1                             1                  0
3                   1                             1                  0
4                   1                             1                  0
5                   0                             1                  0
6                   1                             1                  0
  Garden.Division Novelty.Gift.Division Jewelry.Division
1               0                     1                0
2               1                     1                1
3               1                     1                1
4               1                     1                0
5               1                     1                0
6               1                     1                1
```

Thank you for your help - sorry for the late reply, I've got a lot on my plate at the moment and this is the first time I've had a chance to check anything.

Comment: We really need to see a line or two of the CatalogSales.csv data file. Do you really have 20 columns of data but only 10 column headings? You can permanently delete the blank columns with  `cross.sell <- cross.sell[, 1:10]`.

Comment: I've seen this when the data originates in Excel, and at some point there was something in columns 11 and beyond but the data was somewhat-deleted (but Excel still considers it part of the `.UsedRange` or whatever the property is). Verify in the original data that something exists in those other columns. At a minimum for us, give us the output of `readLines("CatalogSales.csv", n=4)` so we can see more than what R is giving you.

Comment: I've edited my original post to include the readLines as requested, thank you!

Comment: Exactly. See all of those trailing commas. Those are blank fields not zeros. That is your problem. Read the data and then drop the last 10 columns from the data frame like I suggested above.

Comment: > head(cross.sell, n=1)
  Clothing.Division Housewares.Division Health.Products.Division
1                 0                   1                        1
  Automotive.Division Personal.Electronics.Division Computers.Division
1                   1                             1                  0
  Garden.Division Novelty.Gift.Division Jewelry.Division
1               0                     1                0
> table(is.na(cross.sell))

 FALSE   TRUE 
 44982 495054 
> dim(cross.sell)
[1] 60004     9

Comment: Disregard!  I just learned the value of exploring an imported dataset with BOTH head() and tail(). Apparently my data ended at row 4998 and not 60004, which is why I was getting so many NA results.

Thank you for your help!